# to_json and to_xml giving different outputs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, activesupport

Beginning rails programmer here.  I'm trying to convert a hash to both xml and json, but the output is different.

Here's the hash:

```
{:exchangeRates=>[{:baseCurrency=>"USD", :quoteCurrency=>"EUR", :amount=>1, :nprices=>1, :conversions=>[{:date=>Tue, 20 Nov 2012 21:00:00 +0000, :ask=>"0.7813", :bid=>"0.7813"}]}, {:baseCurrency=>"CAD", :quoteCurrency=>"EUR", :amount=>1, :nprices=>1, :conversions=>[{:date=>Tue, 20 Nov 2012 21:00:00 +0000, :ask=>"0.7839", :bid=>"0.7837"}]}]}
```

Here's the corresponding render code

```
format.json { render :json => { :response => rates.to_hash() } }
```

and here's the JSON (which is what I want)

```
{"response": {"exchangeRates": [
    {
        "baseCurrency": "USD",
        "quoteCurrency": "EUR",
        "amount": 1,
        "nprices": 1,
        "conversions": [{
            "date": "2012-11-20T21:00:00+00:00",
            "ask": "0.7813",
            "bid": "0.7813"
        }]
    },
    {
        "baseCurrency": "CAD",
        "quoteCurrency": "EUR",
        "amount": 1,
        "nprices": 1,
        "conversions": [{
            "date": "2012-11-20T21:00:00+00:00",
            "ask": "0.7839",
            "bid": "0.7837"
        }]
    }
]}}
```

Here's my xml render code:

```
format.xml { render :xml => rates.to_hash(), :root => 'response' }
```

Here's the xml output (there are extra tags where I put in arrays):

```
<response>
    <exchangeRates type="array">
        <exchangeRate>
            <baseCurrency>USD</baseCurrency>
            <quoteCurrency>EUR</quoteCurrency>
            <amount type="integer">1</amount>
            <nprices type="integer">1</nprices>
            <conversions type="array">
                <conversion>
                    <date type="datetime">2012-11-20T21:00:00+00:00</date>
                    <ask>0.7813</ask>
                    <bid>0.7813</bid>
                </conversion>
            </conversions>
        </exchangeRate>
        <exchangeRate>
            <baseCurrency>CAD</baseCurrency>
            <quoteCurrency>EUR</quoteCurrency>
            <amount type="integer">1</amount>
            <nprices type="integer">1</nprices>
            <conversions type="array">
                <conversion>
                    <date type="datetime">2012-11-20T21:00:00+00:00</date>
                    <ask>0.7839</ask>
                    <bid>0.7837</bid>
                </conversion>
            </conversions>
        </exchangeRate>
    </exchangeRates>
</response>
```

As you can see, it is adding the extra "array" attribute tags, i.e. exchangeRates and conversions.  How do I get this to format the same as the json?  I also don't want the attributes on any of the tags either.  I know you can pass in attributes, such as :root => 'response', but after looking for quite some time, I can't seem to find a listing of these attributes on the web.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where it's best just to go directly to the source code. The `to_xml` method is in the `ActiveModel::Serializer` module, here are the [inline docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb#L169), which don't mention anything about the `type="array"` attribute tags. Dig a bit deeper though and you'll see they appear in the same file on line 130 of a method called [`add_associations`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb#L130).

**rails/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:130**

```
type = options[:skip_types] ? { } : {:type => "array"}
```

That tells us that there's an option called `skip_types`, which appears to be documented nowhere. Try passing that to `to_xml`, and you get the desired behaviour:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.to_xml
#=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<fixnums type=\"array\">\n  <fixnum type=\"integer\">1</fixnum>\n  <fixnum type=\"integer\">2</fixnum>\n  <fixnum type=\"integer\">3</fixnum>\n</fixnums>\n"
a.to_xml(:skip_types => true)
#=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<fixnums>\n  <fixnum>1</fixnum>\n  <fixnum>2</fixnum>\n  <fixnum>3</fixnum>\n</fixnums>\n"
```

You'll notice all the added `type` attributes are gone.

So just pass the same option to `render` and you'll get the desired result:

```
format.xml { render :xml => rates.to_hash(), :root => 'response', :skip_types => true }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Thing is, I want to get rid of that array tag COMPLETELY, i.e., for your example, my desired xml would be:
`<?xml version=1.0?><fixnum>1</fixnum><fixnum>2</fixnum><fixnum>3</fixnum>`.  After looking at the code, I don't think this seems possible.  Perhaps I can go back to the designer and have them change the output to include that wrapper tag as that seems the correct way of generating the xml.  What do you think?

Comment: I see. But that's not really what you asked. You said you wanted the xml to be like the JSON, and in the JSON there is the key named `"exchangeRates"` followed by the array. If you take out the tag altogether then (the way I see it) you are creating xml which is different from the JSON.